# Combine filtering (e.g. with grep) with plot function?

Tags: r, plot, filtering

Just getting started with R and I have not been able to find any examples to answer my question!

I have put together a data set that looks like:

```
Sample.Name    Component.name  TCAmount  Ratio
1A-S0          Alprazolam         0.0      0.05
1A-S1          Alprazolam         1.5      0.07
1A-S2          Alprazolam         3.1      0.08
1A-S3          Alprazolam         6.25     0.10
2A-S0          Alprazolam         0.0      0.06
2A-S1          Alprazolam         1.5      0.08
2A-S2          Alprazolam         3.1      0.09
2A-S3          Alprazolam         6.25     0.10
1B-S0          Alprazolam         0.0      0.05
1B-S1          Alprazolam         1.5      0.08
1B-S2          Alprazolam         3.1      0.10
1B-S3          Alprazolam         6.25     0.11`
```

I'm now looking for a way to select all the rows containing "1A" in the Sample.Name column (so that would include 1A-S0, 1A-S1, 1A-S2, 1A-S3) and then have R plot the `Ratio` versus `TCAmount` of only the rows containing this string. Eg. I have come across grep which is able to select rows which contain the term "1A":

```
> df1<-grep(("1A"), alprazolam.df$Sample.Name, value=TRUE)
> df1
```

I get back:

```
 [1] "1A-S0" "1A-S1" "1A-S2" "1A-S3"
```

My question is: how do I command R to now plot the `Ratio` and `TCAmount` for only these columns `grep` picks out? I would prefer not to create a subset of this data to then have to create specific commands pointing to as well since this is already a subset of a larger dataset. If I were to start creating more subsets I will end up with 50 of these data sets times the number of subsets this gets broken into... AH!

If possible, I would ultimately like to be able to create a loop where R knows to use the Sample.Name levels (in this case 1A, 2A, 1B) to create three plots automatically showing the `Ratio` versus `TCAmounts`.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Subsetting certain rows (by some logical condition, whether that's the output from grep or some other logical condition), is called *filtering*. (And subsetting certain columns is called *selecting*). So your question is *"How to filter then plot selected rows"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that uses the package ggplot2 for plotting. It will also create a plot for each of Sample.Name levels in your data (where I assumed the Sample.Name level to be the first two characters in `Sample.Name`). ggplot2 can use a column in your data frame to automatically split the data in group and create several plots.

I first add a column `Sample.Name.Level` to the data frame as follows:

```
alprazolam.df$Sample.Name.Level <- substr(alprazolam.df$Sample.Name, 1, 2)
```

Then the plot is created by

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(alprazolam.df, aes(x = TCAmount, Ratio)) +
    facet_wrap(~ Sample.Name.Level) + geom_line()
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Can I add one further layer to this question? How could I automatically create many ggplots (eg. through a loop) where it will create what you showed above but do it for each different character (drug name) it finds in the `Component.name` column?